# How do I access data from my node.js server from client javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, xmlhttprequest

I'm completely new to Node.JS and I'm trying to get a project up and running where my client Javascript communicates with my Node.JS backend. I've been using `XMLHTTPRequest()` on the client end, but that returns `Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful`. From what I understand I'm getting this because the browser doesn't like making HTTP requests from Javascript? What am I doing wrong? Code:

```
window.onload = function(){
    httpGet("http://localhost:8080");
    console.log("Loaded");
}
function httpGet(url){
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(this.status)
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log("Got names")
       getNamesFromJSONArray(request.responseText);
    };
};
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
request.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", window.parent.INDEX_URL, false);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhttp.send();
var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
console.log("response",response);
```

Comment: window.parent.INDEX_URL means get url

Comment: 1. I get the same error and 2. Synchronous requests are deprecated

Comment: but I got that answer

Comment: What do you mean?